# Show side and top bar not working on all monitors

Tags: gnome, multiple-monitors, extension

I have trouble with my gnome extension for multi monitoring. I whant to show the top bar also on the second monitor, but the extension does not work. Also the warning symbol appears always also after reinstalling.

[image: Screenshot of Ubuntu settings]

The slider is grey and can not moved.

Do you have tips or ideas how to fix that?

Comment: This should show that the "multiple monitors add-on" is not able to get switched on. The basic name is in english, so the german words are not urgent.

Comment: The picture shows the basic problem that the "multiple monitors add-on" is not able to get switched on, the slider is grey. The german words in the add-on are not urgent. Urgent is the fact, that the add-on does not work. I need the extension because i use a pc with desktop monitor and TV.

Comment: No, as i connected the second monitor, the top bar and side bar were not shown. And after setting "show side bar on all displays" i saw the side bar on both, but as i clicked on the apps button the apps list were shown only on the main desktop. And For the top bar no setting was possible.

Comment: Hm, so the Gnome extension is not made for multiple Monitor control? But i think im not the only one who wants to use more monitors with all bars.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution:

- Open Firefox browser to manually add Gnome-shell extensions as add-on in firefox
- search in the GNOME library of firefox addon "Multi Monitors Add-ON"
- in the side select "update manually" now in the picture there is just an "ON" slide switch
  [image]
- accept the updating process
- enjoy all multi monitor features

:-)